# XQuery get data with response Microstrategy

Tags: api, soap, xquery, microstrategy

I've script for this. When i runned report, i can take the returns. Token, Auth Type,Expire Time and scope.
With Microstrategy and XQuery language, i want to get data from other url with using this results.

Here is my post method:

```
import module namespace json = 'http://www.zorba-xquery.com/modules/json';
declare copy-namespaces no-preserve, no-inherit;
declare namespace mstr-rest = 'http://www.microstrategy.com/xquery/rest-functions';
declare function mstr-rest:post($uriResponse,$payloadResponse,$header) external;

let $header := ("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

let $uriResponse := ('https://apiwg/token')
let $payloadResponse := ('grant_type=&amp;username=&amp;password=&amp;client_id=-&amp;client_secret=;scope=')
let $jsonresult := mstr-rest:post($uriResponse,$payloadResponse,$header)
let $response := json:parse($jsonresult)
```

this returns;Token, Auth Type,Expire Time and scope.

Next stage, how can i get data with this token?
Like that;

```
Adress: https://apigw/search=example
Method: GET
Authorization: Bearer 688b9878-177a-4100-b027-8f302319bfda
```

Response: I need that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this community [post](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB439928-Using-an-XQuery-source-to-authenticate-users-for-a-MicroStrategy-project-in-MicroStrategy-9-x-and-10-x?language=en_US).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251007/3585796) a link only answer is considered a bad answer. You can edit it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31534080)